# Why do I have to specify the dataframe twice while selecting rows with logical statements in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax

I'm not sure what the reason might be for having to specify the name of the dataframe twice when selecting rows using conditional statements in Pandas. For example, if I have a dataframe **df**:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 31 |
| Bob | 21 |

when I want to select rows with people over 30 I have to write
`over_thirty = df[df.age > 30]`. Why not simply `df['age' > 30]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
over_thirty = df.query("age > 30")
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. However, what I'm trying to understand is the reason behind this syntax. I mean, to me it seems kind of unnecessary to have to specify the dataframe twice but I understand that there had to be a reason to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

so if you write df[age>3] it will give you output in true or false. I am sure which you not needed

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.